# Cut Down StackTrace with Interceptor

Tags: java, exception, jakarta-ee, logging, interceptor

I have web service where i call methods of business service. In one of the  methods some kind of exception with appropriate message is thrown. In soap I get exception type and its message (everything is OK). But In log file a bunch of stack trace is written (with detail information). I don't need that. All I need in log file are exception type and its message(like in soap response). But I wouldn't like to change log properties, because of another exceptions must be printed out.
**So question is How can I cut down stack trace in log file ?**
I've made efforts to solve this problem with `@Interceptors` annotation bundled on the web method. There my web service method and Interceptor class are shown. Exception is thrown in `getLbsLocationForService` method .

```
@WebMethod
@Override
@Interceptors(InterceptionHandleUtil.class)
public LbsLocation getLbsLocationService(@WebParam(name="ms")String ms, @WebParam(name="serID")Long ser) throws ScAccViolation, LbsException {
    return serviceProcesses.getLbsLocationForService(ms, ser);
}
```

Interceptor class :

```
@Interceptor
public class InterceptionHandleUtil{
    @AroundInvoke
    public Object intercept(InvocationContext invocationContext) throws Exception {
        /*What can I do here to write down in log file just exception type and message*/
        return invocationContext.proceed();
    }
}
```

Comment: For what type of exception you need only message?

Comment: I need message for only `ScAccViolation` exception